# С#, Файл блокирован процессом, хотя все потоки закрыты

Tags: c#, файлы, потоки-данных

Я изучаю C#, и выполняю работу с файлами и потоками.
Однако при выполнении программа выдаёт ошибку

> System.IO.IOException: "Процесс не может получить доступ к файлу, так как этот файл используется другим процессом."

Ошибка появляется в следующем методе

```
private static void WriteInFile(string path, int stringNumber, int number)
    {
        string[] fileLines = File.ReadAllLines(path);
        fileLines[stringNumber] += " " + number;
        File.WriteAllLines(path,fileLines);
    }
```

На строке `File.WriteAllLines(path,fileLines);`

В программе используется поток чтения `fileRead` из файла, но он закрывается перед вызовом метода, в котором происходит ошибка:

```
      fileRead.Close();
      flag = false;
      WriteInFile(path, j, i);
      break;
```

По итогу нет потоков, что могли бы блокировать файл, но, тем не менее, ошибка всё равно возникает.

Метод полностью:

```
 private static void Write(int size, string path)
        {
            bool flag;
            string[] fileLines = new string[GroupCounter(size)];

            for (int i = 0; i < GroupCounter(size); i++)
            {
                fileLines[i] = "" + Math.Pow(2, i);
            }

            File.WriteAllLines(path, fileLines);

            for (int i = 1; i <= size; i++) //Цикл перебора всех значений и распредделения их по группам
            {
                flag = true;
                StreamReader fileRead = new StreamReader(path);

                for (int j = 0; flag && fileRead.ReadLine() != null; j++) //Перебираем имеющиеся строки
                {
                    string[] line = LineFromFile(path, j).Split(' ');
                    for (int k = 0; k < line.Length; k++) //Перебираем строку для сравнения 
                    {
                          //Если значение делится без остатка, то сразу переходим к следующей строке
                        if (i % Convert.ToInt32(line[k]) == 0 )
                        {
                            if (i == Convert.ToInt32(line[k]))
                            {
                                flag = false;
                            }
                            break;
                        } //Иначе если значение последнее в строке, то добавляем в строку текущее значение i
                        else
                        {
                            fileRead.Close();
                            flag = false;
                            WriteInFile(path, j, i);
                            break;
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
```

Comment: Если при компиляции, то ошибка значит, что exe файл, который вы собираетесь собрать уже запущен, и студия не может его перезаписать. То есть старая версия программы не закрылась. К содержанию кода эта ошибка не имеет отношения. Если во время запуска приложения, то это не при компиляции.

Comment: `В программе используется поток чтения` - не вижу никаких потоков, покажите код метода полностью.

Comment: Ошибка возникает при запуске приложения. Да, я обратил внимания на сам поток и оказалось, что достаточно закрыть его не только в каскаде логических проверок, но и дополнительно поставить закрытие в конце цикла, спасибо.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Оказалось, что ошибка крылась в том, что `fileRead.Close()` закрывался в каскаде условий и при его закрытии ещё и в конце внешнего цикла, ошибка исчезла.
То есть, цикл стал выглядеть так:

```
            for (int i = 1; i <= size; i++) //Цикл перебора всех значений и распредделения их по группам
            {
                flag = true;
                StreamReader fileRead = new StreamReader(path);

                for (int j = 0; flag && fileRead.ReadLine() != null; j++) //Перебираем имеющиеся строки
                {
                    string[] line = LineFromFile(path, j).Split(' ');
                    for (int k = 0; k < line.Length; k++) //Перебираем строку для сравнения 
                    {
                          //Если значение делится без остатка, то сразу переходим к следующей строке
                        if (i % Convert.ToInt32(line[k]) == 0 )
                        {
                            if (i == Convert.ToInt32(line[k]))
                            {
                                flag = false;
                            }
                            break;
                        } //Иначе если значение последнее в строке, то добавляем в строку текущее значение i
                        else
                        {
                            fileRead.Close();
                            flag = false;
                            WriteInFile(path, j, i);
                            break;
                        }
                    }
                }
                fileRead.Close();
            }
```

Comment: А потом узнается, что есть такая вещь, как `using`...

Comment: Лучше и надежнее вот так: `using (StreamReader fileRead = ...) { ваш цикл }`, и можно убрать `fileRead.Close()`,  `using` закроет файл на месте второй фигурной скобки автоматически.

Comment: Да, я знаком с использованием `using` для этих целей, но код у меня обращается к другому потоку во вложенной зоне видимости и мне надо закрыть поток перед этим обращением отдельно, `using` тут использовать неудобно.